# @Html.ValidationSummary(true) - What's the true do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have code that contains:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

I looked at the MSDN site and still can't see what setting "true" does?  What I notice is that when I have validation messages that are for fields then it still creates a validation summary DIV that's empty.

Is there a way to supress the creating of the summary DIVs as they don't show anything when for example my field is a duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can specify error messages against the properties or against the model.  Those specified against the model are displayed using the validationsummary().

The bool property indicates if you would like to display the validation summary error messages at the same time as displaying the property error messages. If you choose not to then the property error messages will be displayed to the user first.  Then, when the user has resolved all of those error messages, the summary error messages will be displayed after.

If the bool parameter is true then only model-level errors are displayed.  If the parameter is false then all errors are shown.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between model-level errors and property-level errors?

Comment: [Page 103](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZscWT8HzDVAC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=model+level+errors+vs+property+level+errors&source=bl&ots=GsFx2zZNjV&sig=Ad7Z21QQnw8aeMRPsMfIEnQn1ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiahsem45vPAhUm9IMKHQpHBtw4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=model%20level%20errors%20vs%20property%20level%20errors&f=false) of Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 might help to clarify this.

Comment: @FrostyStraw Property-level errors specify the name of the property in error. Model-level errors do no specify a property name and the errors apply to the overall model; e.g. if multiple properties have a combination of values that are not consistent with your business rules.