# View not showing ValidationSummary and ValidationMessages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                @Html.Label("Employee number", new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="a">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeNo, new {@class="form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeNo)
            </div>
        </div>
       /*
       * other fields
       */
}
```

and Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,EmployeeNo,Name,Surname,ContactInfo,RoleId")] User user)
{
    ValidateRequestHeader(Request);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWork.userRepository.Update(user);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Index") });
    }
    //ModelState.AddModelError("", "Niepoprawne dane");
    ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(unitOfWork.roleRepository.Get(), "Id", "RoleName", user.RoleId);
    return PartialView(user);
}
```

and model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.DeviceUsages = new HashSet<DeviceUsage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Brak numeru pracownika")]
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Brak imienia")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Brak nazwiska")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Brak Adresu email")]
    public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

`Data annotations` are working. If I leave eg. Name empty `ModelState` is not Valid in controler. But validation messages are not shown. If I uncomment this line: 
`ModelState.AddModelError("", "Niepoprawne dane");` this will be the only `Model error` shown in the View.

Where is a mistake in my code?

Comment: Are you using the same views? I'm asking this because the method you posted returns a partial view.

Comment: Yes. Edit is a PartialView loaded into modalWindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` means excludePropertyErrors = true

Comment: Ok but in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635406/html-validationsummarytrue-whats-the-true-do) They said that true=show `model level error` Errors thrown by model annotations aren't model lvl errors?

Comment: model level errors are errors without name. Errors thorwn by model annotations are property level errors