# Html.ValidationMessageFor doesn't generate html

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I have simple form with get request, but jquery validate unobtrusive does not generate HTML for validation message.

I don't know what is wrong =(


**Razor:**

```
<form class="input-form" action="someUrl" method="get">
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   @for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
      @{
        var newId = Guid.NewGuid();
      }

       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new { @class = "input-item", id = newId })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Value, "message", new { @class = "error", id = newId})
   }

    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
<form class="input-form" action="someUrl" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input class="input-item" id="Value" name="Value" id="fcacdcb4-02fb-4701-8b8a-a0aa1d5799ae" type="text" value="0">
   <input class="input-item" id="Value" name="Value" id="590afe32-3266-497d-ad3b-b1f9939540ef" type="text" value="0">
   <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are not elements with validation message.


I have this Model in **C#:**

```
    public class InputViewModel
    {
        public HtmlString Description { get; set; }

        public string Alias { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also have the necessary scripts in the parent view:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know what I missed.

**UPD:**
Unfortunately I can not show the production code, but it is almost the same as in the question. 

I still can’t understand what I'm doing wrong and why there is no validation div in the result HTML.=( 

Can you tell me more options for validating fields on the client?

Comment: You're rendering inputs with same ID, each HTML element should have Unique ID, you have to fix this first, and take a look at this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635406/html-validationsummarytrue-whats-the-true-do

Comment: I fixed id, but nothing happened (see update in question)

Comment: Is there any way to see full code? I tested it and work for me (and the validation works for first input)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not show the production code, but it is almost the same as in the question. 
I still can’t understand what I'm doing wrong and why there is no validation div in the result HTML. =(
Can you tell me more options for validating fields on the client?