# Client side & Server side validations in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side-validation, server-side-validation

In the ViewModel, I have Data Annotations for few fields.

```
public class EmployeeContactInfoVM
{

[Key]
public int slNo { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Employee GlobalView ID *")]
[StringLength(8,MinimumLength = 8,ErrorMessage ="GV ID should be 8 digits")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please use Numeric data")]
public string EmployeeID { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name *")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ ]*[a-zA-Z]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please use letters")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

}

My View code is given below

```
@model EmployeeContactInformation.ViewModel.EmployeeContactInfoVM
@using EmployeeContactInformation.Classes;
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section Scripts
{
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=@ViewBag.SiteKey"></script>
  <script>
      function CreateToken() {
          $.blockUI();
          grecaptcha.execute('@ViewBag.SiteKey', { action: 'homepage' }).then(function (token) {
              document.getElementById("tokenID").value = token;
              document.EmpContactFrm.submit();
      });
    }
  </script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EmployeeContactInformation", FormMethod.Post, new { name ="EmpContactFrm", id = "EmpContactFrmID" }))
{
  <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <input type="hidden" id="tokenID" name="token" />

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:5px">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeID, new { @class = "col-md-2 editor-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10 inputText">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmployeeID, htmlAttributes: new { @title = "Employee 
            GlobalView ID should consist of 8 digits and in some countries it may start with a leading 
            zero" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "editor-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="inputText col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurName, new { @class = "editor-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 inputText">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SurName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-create btnSave" style="font-size: 
             large;font-weight: 600;padding: 10px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The form gets submitted in CreateToken function ( document.EmpContactFrm.submit(); ).

I am assuming that all of the validations happen at client Side as I have included 
    
    
in configuration file.

Some of the validation happen at Client side for e.g If I input 7 digit EmployeeID, I get an message saying "GV ID should be 8 digits".

When I submit the form without entering for mandatory fields, client Side validation doesn't work, the control comes to Action Method.

I have included Server Side Validation like if(ModelState.IsValid) in the code, this will now throw validation error when I miss Mandatory fields.

Do I need to include validation at both Server & Client End?
I was assuming that if we include jquery unobtrusive file & the above mentioned config settings, validations can be purely at client side.

Please let me know

Comment: <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action=""></form>   comments this line because its form tag inside form tag so it might creating some conflict. Try to comment and let us know result

Comment: It didn't work. client side validations are not working when I submit the form, where as it works when I input wrong data  for FirstName( numeric data in FirstName)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

to

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635487/4264614)

Comment: Yes...I tried your solution...It didn't meet my requirements
When I hit submit button, the postback call happens & server side validation takes place. Is there a way to avoid postback call? and achieve 100% client side validation